# Are the antidiagonals of an enumeration of binary sequences contained in the set of complementary sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Let $F:\Bbb{N}\to[2]^\Bbb{N}$ and $H:\Bbb{N}\to[2]^\Bbb{N}$, such that...

$$\forall i,j\in\Bbb{N}.H_{i,j}=1-F_{i,j}$$

Define the antidiagonals of $F$ as the sequences $d_i:\Bbb{N}\to[2]$ such that...

$$\forall i,j\in\Bbb{N}.d_{i,j}=1-F_{j+i,j}$$

Is it the case that $\forall m\in\Bbb{N}.\exists n\in\Bbb{N}.d_m=H_n$?

**Edit:**

In retrospect, it seems obvious that the answer should be "no," so I would like add a little bit about the context in which the question arose.

Let $F:\Bbb{N}^2\to[2]$ such that $F(n)$ is the $n^{th}$ binary sequence containing finitely many nonzero entries (given reverse lexicographic order) - i.e. $F(1)=(0,0,0,\ldots)$, $F(2)=(1,0,0,0,\ldots)$, $F(3)=(0,1,0,0,\ldots)$, and so forth. This was the test case under consideration when I thought of the question, with the (false) understanding that I could do something similar for any enumeration of binary sequences.

Let $H(m,n)=1-F(m,n)$. The sequence $(H_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ provides an enumeration of the complementary sequences of $F$.

At a glance, it seems that for each antidiagonal $d_i$ of $F$ there is some $n$ such that $H_n=d_i$. Specifically, the $n^{th}$ antidiagonal of $F$ is equal to $H_{A102370(n)}$ (see [A102370(n)](https://oeis.org/A102370)).

---

Note: $[n]=\{m\in\Bbb{N}\mid m<n\}$

Note: $\displaystyle Y^X=\prod_{x\in X}Y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this notation a bit confusing, so let me start by rephrasing things.

I'm going to think of functions $\mathbb{N}^2\rightarrow [2]$ instead, so that your "$F_{i,j}$" is written "$F(i,j)$" (etc.). You also use single-variable subscripts in this context; for $G:\mathbb{N}^2\rightarrow [2]$, I'm going to assume $G_i$ is the "slice" $$G_i:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow [2]: j\mapsto G(i,j).$$

We now have three maps $\mathbb{N}^2\rightarrow [2]$:

- An arbitrary one $F$.
- The "complement" of $F$, namely $H(i,j)=1-F(i,j)$.
- The "antidiagonal" of $F$, the map $d(i,j)=1-F(i+j,j)$. *(I'm not actually sure where the name comes from here.)*

And you're asking whether each $$d_m: n\mapsto 1-F(m+n, n)$$ is equal to some $H_k$. This is equivalent to asking whether for each $m$ there is some $k$ such that for all $n$ we have $$\color{red}{(d_m(n)=)}\quad 1-F(m+n,n)=1-F(k, n)\quad\color{red}{(=H_k(n))}.$$ And it's easy to see that the answer to this question is **no**: consider, for example, the map $F$ defined by

- $F(a,b)=1$ iff $a=b$.
- $F(a,b)=0$ iff $a\not=b$.

This is a counterexample to the claim, since for every $m, k$ there is some $n$ such that $1-F(k,n)=0$ (namely, $k=n$) but there is no $n$ such that $1-F(m+n, n)=0$.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Follow up question: for which enumerations $F$ *is* this the case?

Comment: @R.Burton I don't know that you'll get a snappier description than the definition itself. If it helps, you can rephrase it as: "For each $m$ there is some $k$ such that for all $n$ we have $F_{m+n}(n)=F_k(n).$"